# undefined field store_id on catalog search reindex, magento 2 with solr search

Tags: magento-2.0.2, solr

I have configured the solr-4.10.4 with magento 2.0.2 and tested the connecton.Connection is successful but when i tried to reindex i am getting the "undefined field store_id" exception, please provide your suggestion on this problem.[image: screen shot of command prompt with solr exception]

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue on Solr end but catalog search configuration on magento end.

The error means magento is trying to reindex "store_id" field but it couldn't find "store_id" on schema.xml file. In other words, you should explicitly define Solr Server Path on Magento-admin-Stores->Configuration->Catalog->Catalog->Catalog Search. Instead of defining Solr server path as just "solr" , you should define as "solr/magento2" where magento2 is your solr collection defined on solr. This happens when you have multiple collections as it takes default collection when not defined explicitly.

And, collection name isn't checked when connection is tested. A connection test is merely connecting to solr server with IP and port provided. So, successful connection doesn't necessarily guarantee that search works.